# Flutter integration for Siri

Tags: xcode, flutter, siri

I want to say something to Siri like 'Hey Siri show me the menu list in ExampleAPP' then it opens my app with the Siri message. How can I achieve something like this in Flutter, please?

Comment: This sounds difficult. Have you found any code samples or other repositories that provide this function? You should ask something more specific (of where you are stuck) because right now your question is broad.

Comment: I'm still actullay trying to find a document or a guide for the instructions